# Не выводит поменянные местами переменные

Tags: c#

Почему не выводит поменянные местами а и б?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.Write("Введите А: ");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Введите Б: ");
        string b = Console.ReadLine();
        string c = b;
        b = a;
        a = c;
        Console.WriteLine("Новое А: ", a);
        Console.WriteLine("Новое Б: ", b);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы используете не ту перегрузку метода `WriteLine`.

Можно вывести так

```
Console.WriteLine("Новое А:" + a);
Console.WriteLine("Новое Б:" + b);
```

Или если хотите использовать ту которая у вас, то нужно так т.к. первый аргумент - форматируемая строка по аналогии с методом String.Format

```
Console.WriteLine("Новое А: {0}",a);
Console.WriteLine("Новое Б: {0}",b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, не выводит! Вам нужна конкатенация: `"Новое А: "+a`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.Write("Введите А: ");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Введите Б: ");
        string b = Console.ReadLine();
        string c = b;
        b = a;
        a = c;
        Console.WriteLine("Новое А: "+a);
        Console.WriteLine("Новое Б: "+b);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Да, как вам уже ответили, можно применить и форматирование строки: `Console.WriteLine("Новое А: {0}",a);`

К слову, две строки вывода можно заменить одной. Тогда Вам будет легче понять суть форматирования строк; суть конкатенации.

Форматирование:

```
Console.WriteLine("Новое А: {0}\nНовое Б: {1}",a,b);
```

Конкатенация:

```
Console.WriteLine("Новое А: "+a+"\nНовое Б: "+b);
```